# Android HttpUrlConnection returns FileNotFoundException upon trying to send POST and PUT requests with json to API.AI

Tags: android, json, filenotfoundexception, dialogflow-es, http-status-code-400

I am trying to pass a json to API.AI using HttpUrlConnection, but upon trying i get a response code 400 Bad Request, and a FileNotFoundException from the logcat. I get the FileNotFoundException when try to send a POST request to https://api.api.ai/v1/intents?v=20150910, as shown in the documentation for API.AI, and also if i try to send a PUT request to https://api.api.ai/v1/intents/INTENT_ID_HERE?v=20150910. GET request works fine, but is not really what I'm looking for. I have tried sending a cURL, and tried posting json from apigee console online, and both worked fine, so i know the json I'm trying to send is not the problem. I have also tried using HttpsUrlConnection, but it didn't work. I am unable to get more information about what's wrong aside from 400 Bad Request, since Android Studio jumps straight to the IOException catch when it gets to the BufferedReader. I don't know if the problem is related to API.AI. Does anybody have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
private class PostClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private final Context context;

    public PostClass(Context c){

        this.context = c;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        progress= new ProgressDialog(this.context);
        progress.setMessage("Loading");
        progress.show();
    }

    public JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(); {
        try {

            jsonObj.put("name", "change appliance state");
            jsonObj.put("auto", true);
            JSONArray jsonContextsArray = new JSONArray();
            jsonObj.put("contexts", jsonContextsArray);
            JSONArray jsonTemplatesArray = new JSONArray();
            jsonObj.put("templates", jsonTemplatesArray);

            JSONArray jsonUserSaysArray = new JSONArray();
            jsonObj.put("userSays", jsonUserSaysArray);

            JSONArray jsonResponsesArray = new JSONArray();
            jsonObj.put("responses",jsonResponsesArray);
            JSONObject jsonResponses = new JSONObject();
            jsonResponses.put("speech", "Hello, mister");
            jsonResponsesArray.put(jsonResponses);
            JSONObject userSaysObject = new JSONObject();

            JSONArray jsonDataArray = new JSONArray();
            userSaysObject.put("data", jsonDataArray);
            userSaysObject.put("isTemplate", false);
            userSaysObject.put("count", 0);
            jsonUserSaysArray.put(userSaysObject);
            jsonObj.put("priority", 500000);

            JSONObject jsonText = new JSONObject();
            jsonText.put("text", "hello");
            jsonDataArray.put(jsonText);
            Log.d("JSONOBJECT", jsonObj.toString());

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            final TextView outputView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showOutput);
            final String apiToken = "API.AI_DEV_TOKEN";
            URL url = new URL ("https://api.api.ai/v1/intents?v=20150910");

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization ", "Bearer " + apiToken);
            connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type ", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.connect();

            DataOutputStream dStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            dStream.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(jsonObj.toString(), "UTF-8"));
            dStream.flush();
            dStream.close();
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
            System.out.println("Post parameters : " + jsonObj);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

            final StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("Request URL " + url);
            output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Request Parameters " + jsonObj);
            output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator")  + "Response Code " + responseCode);
            output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator")  + "Type " + "POST");
            output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Message" + connection.getResponseMessage());
            Log.d("MESSAGE", connection.getResponseMessage());

            String errorString = connection.getErrorStream().toString();
            Log.d("ERROR", errorString);

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            final StringBuilder responseOutput = new StringBuilder();
            System.out.println("output===============" + br);
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null ) {
                responseOutput.append(line);
            }
            br.close();

            output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Response " + System.getProperty("line.separator") + System.getProperty("line.separator") + responseOutput.toString());


            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    outputView.setText(output);
                    System.out.println("OUTPUT" + responseOutput);
                    progress.dismiss();
                }
            });


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {
        progress.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
10-01 22:42:14.444 15833-16417/com.numetriclabz.sendrequests I/System.out: Response Code : 400
10-01 22:42:14.445 15833-16417/com.numetriclabz.sendrequests D/MESSAGE: Bad Request
10-01 22:42:14.445 15833-16417/com.numetriclabz.sendrequests W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.api.ai/v1/intents?v=20150910
10-01 22:42:14.447 15833-16417/com.numetriclabz.sendrequests W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:238)
10-01 22:42:14.447 15833-16417/com.numetriclabz.sendrequests W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
10-01 22:42:14.447 15833-16417/com.numetriclabz.sendrequests W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
10-01 22:42:14.447 15833-16417/com.numetriclabz.sendrequests W/System.err:     at com.numetriclabz.sendrequests.MainActivity$PostClass.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:143)
10-01 22:42:14.447 15833-16417/com.numetriclabz.sendrequests W/System.err:     at com.numetriclabz.sendrequests.MainActivity$PostClass.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:57)
10-01 22:42:14.447 15833-16417/com.numetriclabz.sendrequests W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
10-01 22:42:14.448 15833-16417/com.numetriclabz.sendrequests W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-01 22:42:14.448 15833-16417/com.numetriclabz.sendrequests W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
10-01 22:42:14.448 15833-16417/com.numetriclabz.sendrequests W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
10-01 22:42:14.448 15833-16417/com.numetriclabz.sendrequests W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
10-01 22:42:14.448 15833-16417/com.numetriclabz.sendrequests W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Are you sure that your url "https://api.api.ai/v1/intents?v=20150910" is addressing a file?

Comment: No, I don't know that. When i type the URL into a browser it returns a json that looks like this:     {"status":{"code":401,"errorType":"unauthorized","errorDetails":"Authentication parameters missing"}}. Does that make it a file?